# ORA-00911: invalid character while retrieving data from db

Tags: java, oracle, jsp

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: 
SELECT * from Employees;
: ORA-00911: invalid character

root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: 
SELECT * from Employees;
: ORA-00911: invalid character

    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:864)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:797)
    org.apache.jsp.select_jsp._jspService(select_jsp.java:109)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
```

Unable to figure where is the invalid character which is throwing the exception

Following is the query string:

```
<sql:setDataSource var="orcl" driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
     url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.6.132:1521:orcl"
     user="jsp" password="jsp"/>

<sql:query dataSource="${orcl}" var="result">
SELECT * from Employees;
</sql:query>
```

Comment: Show us the code where you make the query.

Comment: are you trying to connect to db from jsp page?

Comment: @Nomad Yes trying to connect from jsp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The semicolon is a statement separator. It should not be included when you execute a statement through JDBC (or OCI, etc.), which is what is happening in the background.

So where you currently execute this:

```
<sql:query dataSource="${orcl}" var="result">
SELECT * from Employees;
</sql:query>
```

Change it to:

```
<sql:query dataSource="${orcl}" var="result">
SELECT * from Employees
</sql:query>
```

Comment: and when I remove the semicolon, data retrieved from db is empty when I have the data in the table

Comment: Are you sure you have committed data, in a table your JSP user can see? If you connect to a new session through another client and run that query, do you get data back? You can also try another query as a test, e.g. `select * from dual`, to make sure you are displaying what you get back.

Comment: You are right. I didn't commit the data. Thank Alex